# Does drinking beer after exercise help restore muscles?

Tags: alcohol

About ten years ago I attended a hiking camp. There was a girl who on every evening, after each day of hiking was drinking a full bottle of beer. She even believed everyone should do the same. I don't fully remember the rationale she provided, but it was something about beer relieving sore muscles or perhaps rather something about muscles being contracted after physical activity and both beer and stretching exercises alleviating that.

I find such claims surprising since nowadays increasingly often I keep hearing the opposite: that alcohol is a poison that can only damage the body and be detrimental to physical activity so anyone who wishes to do their body any good, especially if they're exercising, should go teetotal. A few of my work colleagues go to gym regularly. One of them used to drink regularly, but has since gone teetotal because he's concerned with his body weight and gym performance. The other one only drinks very occasionally, for similar reasons.

So just to be absolutely certain: This theory about drinking beer after exercise is pure and utter BS, right?

Just to make absolutely sure: This is all complete and utter BS, right?

Answer (score 2):

Alcohol is unlikely to have any effect either way on recovery from exercise[<sup>1</sup>](https://doi.org/10.3390/jfmk4030041). Excessive alcohol consumption is known to be harmful for multiple reasons, including its calorie content leading to increases in body fat.

So no, it won't help your recovery, but you also don't need to go teetotal. But if you're trying to lose body fat, or if you're drinking to the point where it's causing you harm, then reducing your alcohol intake is likely to be beneficial.

Comment: Small amount probably have little to no effect but I've seen studies that say alcohol negatively affects muscle protein synthesis. So, if muscle building is your primary goal and you want to optimize hypertrophy then you might want to at least minimise alcohol consumption.